# Displaying sum of time by project by user using Django

Tags: python, django, sum

I am a student new to programming. I am working on a project to create a timekeeping function. I want to be able to display the total time a user worked on a project. I have been able to display the total time for a user, and the total time for a project.

```
class User(models.Model):

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name ='made_by', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    projects_working_on = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = "projects_assigned_to")

class Timekeeper(models.Model):
    clock_in = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    clock_out = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    total_time = models.DurationField(null=True, blank=True)
    entire_time = models.FloatField(null=True)
    is_working = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    users_time = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="time_of_user", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    proj_time = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name = 'time_of_project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is is clockout function:

```
def clockout(request, proj_id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.session['userid'])
    now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    this_proj = Project.objects.get(id = proj_id)
    this_time = user.time_of_user.last()
    time = this_time.users_time
    this_time.clock_out = now
    this_time.is_working = False
    newtime = user.time_of_user.filter(proj_time=proj_id).aggregate(Sum('total_time'))
    # this_time.total_time_two = newtime
    this_time.save()
    Timekeeper.objects.update(total_time=F('clock_out') - F('clock_in'))
    Timekeeper.objects.update(entire_time=F('total_time'))
    Timekeeper.objects.update(total_time_two=newtime)
    # Timekeeper.objects.update(entire_time=user.time_of_user.filter(proj_time=proj_id).aggregate(Sum"(F('total_time')")
    return redirect('/dashboard/view/'+str(proj_id))
```

The entire_time field exists solely for another function to iterate through and find the time of all of the fields for a particular user, or project. I can't seem to get a sum of the total_times (or entire_times) of 1 user for a particular project. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to my own post, I found a workable solution: Not the most elegant though.

```
class Timekeeper(models.Model):
    clock_in = models.TimeField(null=True)
    clock_out = models.TimeField(null=True)
    total_time = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    entire_time = models.FloatField(null=True)
    user_total_time = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    user_project_total_time = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_working = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    users_time = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="time_of_user", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    proj_time = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name = 'time_of_project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In views.py

```
def clockout(request, proj_id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.session['userid'])
    this_time = user.time_of_user.last()
    total_time_of_user = 0
    total_time_of_user_project = 0
    for i in user.time_of_user.all():
        total_time_of_user += i.total_time
        this_time.user_total_time = total_time_of_user
        this_time.save()
    for x in user.time_of_user.filter(proj_time=proj_id).all():
        total_time_of_user_project += x.total_time
        this_time.user_project_total_time = total_time_of_user_project
        this_time.save()
```

This creates 2 new attributes to the Timekeeper model.